# .NET Web-Api controller variable as javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass a "variable" from the controller to a javascript function. The code is as follows:

```
 <div ng-controller="faqController">

        <div ng-repeat="c in categories">
            <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('quest{{c.catID}}')">{{c.name}}</h2>
            <ul id="quest{{c.catID}}" class="" ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:{ catID: c.catID}" style="display:none">
                <li>{{q.quest}}</li>
           </ul>
   </div>
```

The problem happens in the `<h2> onclick` where `{{c.catID}}` does not turn in to a number, as it does in the id of `<ul>`. So my question is, how do I get `quest{{c.catID}}` to become `quest[number]`?

Comment: Try toggle_visibility('quest' + c.catID)

Comment: This does not show the catID, so the function is not called with the right parameter.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner if you used `ng-click` and have controller call the JavaScript function instead of directly from the View.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this value would be rendered as a number if you removed the single quotes.

```
<h2 onclick="toggle_visibility(@quest{{c.catID}})">{{c.name}}</h2>
```

Comment: Already tried that, and it does not work. In Visual Studio it says the following when i try it: `Expected ')'` on the first `{` after `quest`. At the last `}` it says: `Syntax error`.

Comment: Updated answer to include the @